# Best IP to Location for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation

I was wondering if anyone had any experience with a good plugin/gem that pulls city and state from the IP.  I've tried the one built into GeoKit but it's terrible.  I don't mind paying for it as well but I would prefer free.

Comment: What made you determine it was terrible?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703511/

Comment: It hasn't correctly resolved the location of any IPs I've given it

Answer (score 8):

One of the best IP to location products is MaxMind's GeoIP.

The MaxMind GeoIP City does cost (http://www.maxmind.com/app/city), but there is also the MaxMind GeoLite City (http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity) which is free, but a bit less accurate and not as frequently updated.

Answer (score 7):

try this one http://www.rubygeocoder.com/

Comment: FYI, this gem is essentially useless on heroku because the API is rate limited by IP and you're going to be making requests from a cluster of shared IP addresses

Comment: Anecdotally, their demo cannot locate my IP (in Canada) however MaxMind's free GeoIP database gets it right.