# Access current location of user using IP address

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Is there any solution that i can access user current location,

I use geocoder gem

```
@request = request.location
```

but it give reserved or nil entry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best IP to Location for Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107681/best-ip-to-location-for-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all put this code in your html page

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>
```

you will get Latitude & Longitude of that location from this code.Then after use this value of Latitude & Longitude with geocoder gem.
you will able to find address of that location.

you can also see this from here.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: Can i know what is wrong in this answer? because some one is dislike this