# Rails 3.2.3 GeoLocation Using MaxMind

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geolocation, ip

I'm completely new to rails and started playing with by taking an existing side project from PHP into Rails. Currently I'm using the MaxMind GeoLocation [Pecl extension in PHP](http://www.maxmind.com/app/php).

I'd like to know if there's an equivalent to Rails? I've searched Google and found a few prospects, but I'm also using Rails 3.2.3.

My question is what is comparable to the Pecl geolocation extension in rails? I did find [this](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ruby), but have not set it up yet.

I did find the [Ruby Geocoder](http://rubygeocoder.com/) last night, which does seem promising

Comment: Here is a link to a similar question on SO

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703511/ruby-geolocation-gem-plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try https://github.com/imajes/geokit-gem?