# How to store and find records based on location?

Tags: ruby, gps, location, zipcode

I'm thinking of building an application that helps you find local businesses (just an example). You might enter your zip code (or GPS if this is on a phone) and find the closest business within 10 miles, etc. My question is how can I achieve this type of logic? Is there a library or service that I will need to use? Or can this be done with math? I'm not familiar with how this sort of thing usually works, so let me know how I need to store the records so I can query them later. Note: I will be using Ruby and MongoDB.

Comment: You could use longitude and latitude to help calculate the distance, with mixing some maths in it (which I don't know), and some map service (possibly Google Maps) to help convert a zip code into long/lat. That might work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be easy to find the math to solve that, providing lat/long coordinates.

Or you could use some full featured gem to do that for you like [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder), that supports Mongoid or MongoMapper.

Next time you need some feature that might be a commun world problem, first check if there is a gem for that at [ruby-toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com), for this case here are some other gems for [geocoding](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/geocoding___maps)

Comment: That geocoder gem looks awesome. And thanks for the link to Ruby Toolbox!

Answer (score 0):

One more solution here...

http://geokit.rubyforge.org/

I think, this topic is already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703511/ruby-geolocation-gem-plugins)..